# Overloaded parenthesis operator

Tags: c++

I'm using the EasyBMP library. I have a function that returns a `BMP*` object. BMP objects have the parenthesis overloaded, where I can do:

```
BMP image;
*image(x,y)->Red=0;
```

But now that I'm trying to return a pointer, I want to do:

```
BMP *image;
*image(x,y)->Red=0;
```

but I get an error saying that image cannot be used as a function. How do I fix this?

Comment: BTW it's called the function-call operator.

Comment: What an abomination of a syntax.

Comment: @shoosh Sweet Jesus, you are so right!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
BMP* image = getimageptr();
*(*image)(x,y)->Red=0;
```

Or, perhaps better:

```
BMP* image_ptr = getimageptr();
BMP& image = *image_ptr;
*image(x,y)->Red=0;
```

(BTW, do you *really* dereference that object returned by `op()` before dereferencing it *again* to access `Red`? Seems odd!)

Comment: Yes, well played using the reference.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that in the second example, `image` is of type `BMP*`, not `BMP`; since `operator()` is overloaded on `BMP`, you need to dereference the pointer before you use the call operator.

Hence, I think you will need to use:

```
*(*image)(x,y)->Red = 0;
```

I'm away from a compiler right now, so you'll have to forgive me if I messed up.

Comment: @bitmoe: Why do you think that?

Comment: @bitmoe Indeed; `(*image)(x,y)->Red = 0` will most absolutely _not_ do what you wanted, unless `Red` is not a pointer; (if `Red` is a pointer, you'll just end up zeroing it out).

Answer (score 0):

Please read through the [C++ FAQ #13.10](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/operator-overloading.html#faq-13.10).  This FAQ item discusses overloading `operator()` for use with matrices.  I believe this is what you want to do.

The FAQ also shows how to use the operator as well.